# Get list of installed cookbooks along with their version

Tags: chef-infra

I have a server that has been provisioned via chef. Now I like to know exactly which cookbook versions have been installed on this server.

Being a chef-newbee, I worked around using `grep` like the following, but I like to know whether or not there is some official way of getting that information.

```
sudo grep -E '^version|"version":' /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/*/metadata*
```

Is there a `chef` command that lists all the installed cookbooks along with their versions?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
knife cookbook list | awk '{printf "knife cookbook show %s\n",$1}'| bash
```

Will print out the versions associated with each cookbook. For example:

```
java   1.31.0  1.29.0
mysql   6.0.22  6.0.21
rbac   1.0.3
smf   2.2.6
yum   3.6.0
yum-mysql-community   0.1.17
```

Comment: Doesn't that lists the cookbooks that are available to be installed? What I want to know is what has currently been installed.

Comment: knife cookbook list  --> list the installed cookbooks; knife cookbook show <cookbook name> --> show all versions of the cookbook in the argument

Comment: @muhqu The command generates a set of knife commands that shows all the versions of each cookbook installed on the chef server.

Comment: Exactly, but that was not what I was asking for. I want to know which cookbooks (and version) has been deployed to the 'node'. E.g. Where chef-client runs.

Comment: @muhqu That is not a simple thing to do. The runlist is calculated at run-time and unless you have a version constrained runlist will depend on what what cookbooks are loaded into the chef server. I recommend clearing the client cache and running chef client-client again to see what you currently have. In the long run consider using a chef environment with cookbook version constraints set. (Another question methinks)

Comment: I ran the command as root on CentOS 6.6. Got this error: WARNING: No knife configuration file found. ERROR: ArgumentError: Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that :node_name is assigned.

Comment: @user674669 Different question. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168084/how-to-add-knife-rb-into-environment-variables

Answer (score 3):

Variation on some of the above.

```
sudo grep -o -e '\"version\"\:\"[a-zA-Z0-9.]*\"' -e '\"version\"\: \"[a-zA-Z0-9.]*\"' /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/*/metadata.json
```

Comment: I got this error on CentOS 6.6: grep: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/*/metadata.json: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on CentOS 6.6:

```
for filename in `ls /var/cache/chef/cookbooks`; \
do \
    echo -n "$filename "; \
    grep version /var/cache/chef/cookbooks/$filename/metadata.rb; \
done | column -t
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

First of all there is no oficial chef way to get list of cookbooks versions installed.

But you can use such tools as [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) or [librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef), put all cookbooks you need.