# How to add knife.rb into environment variables

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am getting error when i am trying to run knife command

```
knife client list

WARNING: No knife configuration file found
ERROR: ArgumentError: Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that
:node_name is assigned
```

If i run knife command from repository directory then it's work.

How i can include path of my knife.rb file into environment variables so that i can run knife commands from any location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your knife config file in `~/.chef/knife.rb` instead. That is used as the default if no local file is found.