# Which command could be used for extracting cookbooks for current run list via chef-client under *UNIX system?

Tags: centos, chef-infra, cookbook

#### Env:

```
chef-client --version
Chef: 14.3.37
```

#### Description:

Chef-client was run via following command

```
chef-client -c <file.rb> -j <file.json> -E <env> 2>&1 > file.log
```

After executing `file.log` contains following line about list of resolved cookbooks for current run:

```
[time] INFO: Loading cookbooks [a@1.1.1, b@1.1.1, c@1.1.1, d@1.1.1, e@1.1.1]
```

#### Question:

Via which command for `chef-client` (not `knife`!) I could extract such list of cookbooks with versions?

#### PS:

Parsing of logs is not great idea is firts.
There is no way to configure `knife` - second.

Comment: I've found solution via grep - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230042/4436022 but it's a little bit weird, that `chef-client` doesn't have such API.

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to access the expended recipe run-list, use `node['recipes']`.

if you are interested in the node's roles, use `node['roles']`

note that these are node attributes, which means that you can access them same as you access any other node attribute.

Comment: there is an issue - node name is unknown + it is deleted by script after chif-run :) Grep (from my comment) solve my question, but not via `chef-client`

Comment: @YuriyLeonov: please see my updated answer. these are node attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write a recipe, that saves all the required information into some file in required format, and include this recipe into run list. Then every time Chef-client is run, it will update the file.

As Mr. pointed out, the expanded run-list can be taken from the node['recipes'] attributes, so it's very easy to extract the required info.